# React not Finding <input/> Value in Submit Handler

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, reactive-programming

Here's my React class:

```
var React = require('bower.js').React;
var paper = require('bower.js').paper;

var NotePanel = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      noteToAdd: ""
    };
  },
  setNoteToAdd: function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var note = this.refs.noteToAdd.value;
    console.log(this.refs.noteToAdd.value);
    this.setState({
        noteToAdd: note
    });
  },
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div>
        <form onSubmit={this.setNoteToAdd}>
          <input ref="noteToAdd" type="text" />
          <input type="submit" value="Add Note" />
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
});

module.exports = NotePanel;
```

It follows closely the code in `tutorial16.js` [here](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/tutorial.html) (greater than halfway down the page).

However, the line

```
console.log(this.refs.noteToAdd.value);
```

prints undefined to the console. I'm not sure what I'm missing. The ref seems to be set up properly. The render code is very similar to that of the tutorial. But in the click handling function I cannot access the `value` of the `input` `ref` like in the tutorial. Why is this?

Comment: What version of React are you using?

Comment: Also, you don't have a `click` handler, you have a `submit` handler.

Comment: Try console.log(note) - I bet this works

Comment: @Mathletics React v0.12.2, changed title, thanks

Comment: @Titus No, it didn't, what's your thinking? They should produce the same thing since that's what I set `note` to.

Comment: @ScottH Hm, just because I've had similar experiences with logging being incosistent in React, but where the actual running of the program was not affected. Almost like it gets out of sync by the time you go to log it

Comment: Hm, it works as for me  [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/17665/)

Comment: @The He's using a different version of React though - that might be it?

Comment: I'm now trying upgrading to React v0.14.0

Comment: @Titus, Yeap you are right. it can be a problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In **v0.12.0** use `this.refs.noteToAdd.getDOMNode().value`

In **v0.13.0** use `React.findDOMNode(this.refs.noteToAdd).value`

In **v0.14.0** use `this.refs.noteTOAdd.value`

Answer (score 1):

Try;

```
this.refs.noteToAdd.getDOMNode().value
```